# Send Receive Char * between parent and child processes

Tags: c, pipe, fork

Im trying to get the string in the parent process and pass it to the child who then sends back a string stating its strength based on the passTest() method. it seems to send the string to the child properly but it then says that it failed the read condition on the parent before it finishes evaluating the received string in the child process. The parent should be waiting for the child to write because of this shouldnt it?

```
len = read(fd[P1_READ], val, tend);
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>    
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

//  Parent: reads from P1_READ, writes on P1_WRITE
//  Child:  reads from P2_READ, writes on P2_WRITE
#define P1_READ     0
#define P2_WRITE    1
#define P2_READ     2
#define P1_WRITE    3
#define NUM_PIPES   2
#define false       0 //Used for testing password strength

//Prototypes for other functions
char * passTest(char * password);
char * getPass(char * password);


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int fd[2*NUM_PIPES];
    int len, i;
    char * val = malloc(100);
    pid_t pid;
    int tend;

    // create all the descriptor pairs we need
    for (i=0; i<NUM_PIPES; ++i)
    {
        if (pipe(fd+(i*2)) < 0)
        {
            perror("Piping Failed");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
    //FORK ERROR
    if ((pid = fork()) < 0)
    {
       perror("Fork Error");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    //child process
    if (pid == 0)
    {
        // Child. CLOSE UNNEEDED FD
        close(fd[P1_READ]);
        close(fd[P1_WRITE]);

        // used for output
        pid = getpid();

        // wait until parent sends a value
        len = read(fd[P2_READ], val, tend);
        if (len < 0)
        {
            perror("Child: Failed to read data from pipe\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        else if (len == 0)//In case nothing in pipe
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Child: Read EOF from pipe\n");
        }
        else
        {
            // report what was recieved
            printf("Child(%d): Received >%s<\n", pid, val);
            val = passTest(val); //CHECK PASSWORD
            tend = strlen(val);
            printf("Child(%d): Sending >%s< back\n", pid, val);
            if (write(fd[P2_WRITE], val, tend) < 0)
            {
                perror("Child: Failed to write response value");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }
        // finished. close remaining descriptors.
        close(fd[P2_READ]);
        close(fd[P2_WRITE]);

        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
        //END CHILD PROCESS
    }else{
    //PARENT PROCESS
    // Close unused FD
        close(fd[P2_READ]);
        close(fd[P2_WRITE]);

    // used for output
        pid = getpid();

    // send password to child
        val = getPass(val);
        strtok(val, "\n"); 
        tend = strlen(val);
        printf("Parent(%d): Sending %s to child\n", pid, val);
        if (write(fd[P1_WRITE], val, tend) != tend)
        {
        perror("Parent: Failed to send value to child ");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

// now wait for a response
    len = read(fd[P1_READ], val, tend);
    if (len < 0)
    {
        perror("Parent: failed to read value from pipe\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else if (len == 0)
    {
    // not an error, but certainly unexpected
        fprintf(stderr, "Parent(%d): Read EOF from pipe\n", pid);
    }
    else
    {
    // report what we received
        printf("Parent(%d): Received %s\n", pid, val);
    }

// close descriptors
    close(fd[P1_READ]);
    close(fd[P1_WRITE]);

// wait for child termination
    wait(NULL);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
}//END MAIN


char * getPass(char * password){
    printf("Please enter the password: ");
    fgets(password, 50, stdin);
    return password;
}

char * passTest(char * password){
    printf("INSIDE passTest %s\n",password);
    char * passStrength = "";
    int   i=0;
    int  found_lower = false, found_upper = false, found_number =false;

    while(password[i] != '\0' || !(found_lower && found_upper&&        found_number)) {
        found_lower = found_lower || (password[i] >= 'a' && password[i] <= 'z');
        found_upper = found_upper || (password[i] >= 'A' && password[i] <= 'Z');
        found_number = found_number ||(password[i] >= '0' && password[i] <= '9');
        i++;
    }
    if(found_lower && found_upper&& found_number){
        strcpy(passStrength, "strong");
    }else{
        strcpy(passStrength, "weak");
    }
    if(strlen(password)<8){
        strcpy(passStrength, "short");
    }
    printf("passStrength >%s<\n",passStrength);
    return passStrength;
}
```

Comment: So should i only be using 2 file descriptors. One for parent to write to and child to read and one for child to write and parent to read?

Comment: For the record, you're not actually sending or receiving `char *`, you're sending and receiving `char`s stored sequentially at the location a `char *` points to. Sending the actual pointer across the pipe would be pointless; each process has a separate address space, so using the pointer from one process in a different process would be undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Problems I noticed:

**Problem 1**

The variable `tend` is not initialized.

I would change

```
int tend;
```

to

```
int tend = 100; // Or anything else that makes sense in your application.
```

**Problem 2**

You have

```
char * passStrength = "";
```

and proceed to use

```
strcpy(passStrength, "strong");
```

that definitely leads to undefined behavior. Make sure you have enough memory in `passStrength` to hold the values you want to assign to it.

and then you use:

```
return passStrength;
```

that will be good only if the memory used by `passStrength` lives beyond the function call. You have to use:

```
static char passStrength[100];  // Make it large enough.
```

or

```
char * passStrength = malloc(100);
```

**Problem 3**

In all calls to `write`, you are sending a string without the terminating null character, such as:

```
  tend = strlen(val);
  printf("Parent(%d): Sending %s to child\n", pid, val);
  if (write(fd[P1_WRITE], val, tend) != tend)
```

When you read the data on the other end of the pipe(s), the strings are null terminated. Using those strings as though they are null terminated strings leads to undefined behavior. You can fix this by either:

1. Sending one more character.

   ```
   if (write(fd[P1_WRITE], val, tend+1) != tend+1)
   ```

   or
2. Adding the null character after you read the data.

   ```
   len = read(fd[P1_READ], val, tend);
   val[len] = '\0';
   ```

**Problem 4**

The `while` statement is `passTest` is not setup right. Because of that, the function accesses memory beyond the valid range. That causes undefined behavior.

Change it to:

```
while( password[i] != '\0' && ( false == found_lower ||
                                false == found_upper ||
                                false == found_number ) ) {
```

I found the following easier to understand:

```
while( password[i] != '\0' ) {
   if ( found_lower && found_upper && found_number ) {
      break;
   }
   found_lower = found_lower || (password[i] >= 'a' && password[i] <= 'z');
   found_upper = found_upper || (password[i] >= 'A' && password[i] <= 'Z');
   found_number = found_number ||(password[i] >= '0' && password[i] <= '9');
   i++;
}
```

Comment: Weird, It still isnt working for me. Even after initializing tend. It gets inside the passTest and the parent process comes back with an error before it should have been called.

Comment: I've since done all these and im still getting the same error i was before.